# CSS3 Pie.htc and password input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I'm trying to use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) in order to add support for border radius in IE8.

I've added the correct behaviour to the styles which use `border-radius` and it's almost perfect except that it is very glitchy when it comes to applying the style to password input fields e.g

```
<input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" />
```

Sometimes it will load the element fine but most of the time, the password field is not rendered in my document if I apply the `PIE.htc` behaviour to it.

If I set the `TextMode` of the control to `Text` e.g. `type="text"` then it will work fine but I lose the functionality I'm after which is hiding the users input in the password field. The style applied to the field is as follows:

```
#login-form input, a.btn-login {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 320px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-size: 18px;
   position: relative;
   behavior: url(../CMSScripts/Custom/PIE.htc);
}
```

Anyone else run into this issue using `PIE.htc` before? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I had this problem with inputs in general, sometimes not rendering with css3pie.
if you use relative length on your element like em or percentage, it may not work,
So use PX to set length of your input elements.

Or may be your apache doesn't recognize the htc extension.
so add it in you htaccess file :

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Or may be the path of your PIE.htc is wrong. To be sure I put the file with my css files.

Or add css to your input type text to look like a input type password with this code:

```
input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
/* with this code people won't be able to copy/paste the text in the input */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Hope I save you !

Comment: Hi, I am using pixel values for the width and height of the input elements as you can see in my post. I'm not using apache and I have the correct path to the PIE.htc file as it works fine for other elements on the same page. It's just not rendering inputs with `type="password"`

Comment: Not a bad idea actually. However `-webkit-text-security` is not an IE property

Comment: yes I was looking for if it exists for IE.
But I think your problem is not a pie issue it may be in your own code. actually I test for an input type password with border radius with IE8 and it works fine using PIE.htc.
The best way for you is to simulate a input password on an input text.
Using javascript certainly..

Comment: Like I said. It *sometimes* renders the password field fine and sometimes doesn't. So while it does work, it's not exactly reliable. It's very strange.